# prepend a string to group_concat mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

This statement...

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT  c_style.clrdesc
  ORDER BY  c_style.clrdesc DESC
  SEPARATOR '|'
) AS Attributes
```

takes this table...

```
STYLE CLRDESC
1058  BLACK
1058  BLUE
1058  RED
```

and returns...

```
STYLE ATTRIBUTES
1058  BLACK|BLUE|RED
```

I'd like to take this one step further and prepend a fixed string before the color values in the `ATTRIBUTES` column...

```
STYLE ATTRIBUTES
1058  string of text|BLACK|BLUE|RED
```

I've tried nesting the statement with `CONCAT` but I'm receiving an error.

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
CONCAT_WS('|', 'string of text', GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT  c_style.clrdesc
  ORDER BY  c_style.clrdesc DESC
  SEPARATOR '|'
)) AS Attributes
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b71e0/1/0).